# WebApi 2.2 + Chrome = CORS 405 error

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api, cors

I have 2 projects setup:

1. A Website that just uses HTML and durandal and calls a webapi post method using $.ajax. It's on localhost:33432 and calls the second site (note that the ajax call doesn't have anything special on it, other than whatever Durandal is adding and is using the latest 2.x release of jquery)
2. A Web API website that is on localhost:32287 that has cors enabled like this in the global.asax.cs file:

   GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*"));

   The web.config file is bone stock MVC 5.2.2 for both sites. complete with the removes etc. in the    system.webserver section.

   Internet Explorer on the local hosts has no issue, because it doesn't issue an OPTIONS request and thus doesn't have a problem. It does if this gets published to separate domains in production. (we've tried this)

Chrome on the other hand fails getting back a 405 error on the OPTIONS request. Here's what Chrome is sending and receiving:

```
Remote Address:[::1]:47806
Request URL:http://localhost:47806/Contacts/ValidateLogin
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:405 Method Not Allowed
Request Headersview parsed
OPTIONS /Contacts/ValidateLogin HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:47806
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Origin: http://localhost:32287
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.94 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: accept, content-type
Accept: */*
DNT: 1
Referer: http://localhost:32287/XXXXX
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Response Headersview source
Allow:POST
Cache-Control:no-cache
Content-Length:76
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Date:Tue, 02 Sep 2014 20:59:36 GMT
Expires:-1
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
X-SourceFiles:=?UTF-8?B?RDpcTGluY29sbiBQZWFrXFBNTlxEbnNcTHBwLk5ldHdvcmsuQXBpXENvbnRhY3RzXFZhbGlkYXRlTG9naW4=?=
```

As an aside this doesn't happen with GET locally. Chrome just lets it on through without OPTIONS.

Any ideas why I'm getting this error and it's not just going through?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try starting chrome with `--disable-web-security`

Ubuntu 
`google-chrome --disable-web-security`
Or
`chrome.exe --disable-web-security`
And then try again